# Power Apps Modify Dropdown Items Property to List Files From a Specific SP Doc Library Folder

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I have a dropdown menu that is populated with files from a SP document library "Documents" and it excludes folder names using this code on the Items property:

```
Filter(Documents, !IsFolder)
```

This works great but now I need to designate a specific folder "Gold" in the SP document library to list all files from excluding any folder names. How would I modify the Items property code to only list files (not folders) in the "Gold" folder of the SP document library "Documents"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Set the Items property equal to the following.

```
Filter(Documents, 'Folder path'="Shared Documents/SP Fest Demo/" && !IsFolder)
```

Replace "Shared Documents/SP Fest Demo/"  with the full path to the folder.  Make sure to include the closing '/' .  YOu will see that 'Folder path' isn't a match that is delegable since its not indexed and there is no way to make it delegable.